# How to correctly implement an JWT authenticated route on react router V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jwt, react-router-v4

Using the RR V4 docs, this is an example code for `PrivateRoute` (or `AuthenticatedRoute`)

```
const AuthExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <AuthButton/>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/public">Public Page</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/public" component={Public}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

Where the `PrivateRoute` can be implemented as:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

  let token - localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    token ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

My doubts are:

a) Is it enough to check if the token is stored locally to let application render the component?

b) What if the token is expired, how can I avoid the new component to be loaded?

c) Should I make a call to server on at the beginning of `PrivateRoute` to check  token expiration and validity ? That would add another roundtrip to server on every route change.

d) What is the proper way to validate the token without touching the server ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't use react, but I have some experience with JWT tokens.

IMHO the client shouldn't have access to the token at any time. Is should be stored on a cookie and sent along on each call to the server who should be the ONLY one with the key to decript it and access its content. You can define the routes that need the token to be sent, typically something like '/api/*'.

If the token is correct, then it sends the response expected by the client, and if not, it tells the client to redirect to /login (with a 401 or any other way you prefer).

If the token is expired (while requesting something to the server) you can automatically regenerate the key or tell the client to log out or tell the client to ask the server for a new key or whatever you consider the best option, you can also have another token 'refresh_token' to use only to recreate the 'access_token' (which is also a very common solution) .

If you need, I could elaborate more.

Comment: My point is that, using ReactJs, not all routes will need to query the server. If the token is expired, then I can move to another route and continue working in the app. Otherwise validating the token on the server on every request seens too much fetching for something that could be done smarter... What I wanna find out is how this smarter way would work...

Comment: Ok. I understand you don't want to gve the users free rein untill they check the route access. I'd say it's enough to force the PrivateRoutes to call the server. If the JWT token doesn't have much info it's very lightweight, so there is not much extra toll to pay. If the route is not Private, you just don't call unless you need some resource.

Answer (score 0):

JWT by default can store data, you can decode it, to check if the expiration is passed, or any other additional fields that your server was saved there.

The important part is to send it to the server on every API call, to verify the signature & the data with it.

So, my suggestion is for routes it is enough to validate only client side, hacker can bypass that only by modifying the JWT, so because of that every API call from your private routes should be validated with the JWT server side, to check signatures.

Comment: Same comments as @Sandokan answer... What for the routes that does not go to server to fetch data ? ReactJS is a SPA on the client...